# Is it possible to infer the type of a task as generic type, without specifying it in an expression?

Tags: c#, expression

I'm trying to provide a nice API over a wrapper i'm working on and i've run into the following issue:

This is my Sandbox code:

```
public interface ISomeInterface
{
    Task<int> SomeMethod(int i);
    Task<Task<int>> SomeOtherMethod(int i);
}

public class TestClass<TSource>
{
    public TWrap ReturnExpressionAsIs<TWrap>(Expression<Func<TSource, TWrap>> expression)
    {
        return default(TWrap);
    }

    public TImplicit SomeExpressionFromTask<TWrap, TImplicit>(Expression<Func<TSource, TWrap>> expression) where TWrap : Task<TImplicit>
    {
        return default(TImplicit);
    }
}
```

I'm using the code like this:

```
var testProxy = new TestClass<ISomeInterface>();
// Task<int> - working as intended
var ordinaryTypeInfer = testProxy.ReturnExpressionAsIs(d => d.SomeMethod(5));

// int - working as intended
var expressionExplicit = testProxy.SomeExpressionFromTask<Task<int>, int>(d => d.SomeMethod(5));

// compiler error - shouldn't this be possible through type inference?
var expressionImplicitAttempt = testProxy.SomeExpressionFromTask(d => d.SomeMethod(5));
```

basically i am expecting TImplicit to be int for SomeMethod and optionally Task for SomeOtherMethod (however if the optional one is impossible that would make perfect sense for me).

Comment: Would `TImplicit SomeExpressionFromTask<TImplicit>(Expression<Func<TSource, Task<TImplicit>>> expression)` work for you? Do you really need a generic parameter for the task type?

Comment: No, i don't need one actually. Luaan posted an answer shortly before you did, pointing that out to me. Your solution was indeed correct as well. since you didn't post it as an answer, i've rewarded you too. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, not really.

However, you're overcomplicating things. Instead of `TWrap: Task<TImplicit>`, just use the `Task` directly:

```
public TImplicit SomeExpressionFromTask<TSource, TImplicit>
       (Expression<Func<TSource, Task<TImplicit>>> expression)
{
    return default(TImplicit);
}
```

In case where you can't simplify the generic type arguments and constraints, it may make sense to add dummy arguments just for the type inference:

```
public V DoStuff<T, U, V>(Func<T, U> func, V dummy) where U: A<V> { ... }
```

Which allows you to call

```
DoStuff(i => SomeFun(i), default(int));
```

Of course, this is really just a helper method - there's no point in doing that in your core implementation.

Comment: Thanks for your additional comment. I'll make sure to remember that, the next time i'm struggeling to come up with the correct expression.